# jlink plugin fails with io.netty export error

Tags: java, maven, jlink

When im running mvn clean verify with maven-jlink-plugin 3.1.0 plugin, it gives me an error

```
[ERROR] Error: Modules io.netty.codec.xml and io.netty.codec export package io.netty.handler.codec.xml to module io.netty.transport.rxtx
```

Im trying to make custom JRE for my javafx app, im new to this and don't understand what to do with this message

Part of my pom

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jlink-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <!-- configuration elements goes here -->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My module info requires

```
requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires javafx.graphics;
requires io.netty.buffer;
requires io.netty.codec;
requires io.netty.transport;
requires io.netty.common;
requires io.netty.handler;
requires fast.md5;
requires static lombok;
requires java.desktop;
requires com.sun.jna;
requires com.sun.jna.platform;
requires json.simple;
requires com.google.gson;
```